# Rails - Show number of users currently visiting a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, chat, ruby-on-rails-5

I got a page in my App where users can chat. Now I want to display the number of Users that are currently viewing the chatpage.
Is there a way to do that?

I thought of an action, that gets called everytime the site gets loaded from a user and increases the value of a variable and decreases it when the user leaves.

Things to take into consideration:

- reloads
- multiple browserwindows

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem, it gives you a lot of nice stats including what you're looking for. Good luck!